# Passing an AsyncThunkAction to unwrapResult

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm following the Redux Essentials tutorial and I've run into a problem in part 5, [Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic). I'm using TypeScript even though TypeScript is not used in the tutorial because I'm trying to learn both Redux and TypeScript at once.

In the section [Checking Thunk Results in Components](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components), I'm getting a type error when calling Redux's `unwrapResult` function that I have not been able to figure out.

Here's the error:

```
TypeScript error in redux-essentials-example-app/src/features/posts/AddPostForm.tsx(34,22):
Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<Post, InitialPost, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionTypesWithOptionalErrorAction'.
  Property 'payload' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<Post, InitialPost, {}>' but required in type '{ error?: undefined; payload: any; }'.  TS2345

    32 |         setAddRequestStatus("pending");
    33 |         const result = await dispatch(addNewPost({ title, content, user: userId }));
  > 34 |         unwrapResult(result);
       |                      ^
    35 |         setTitle("");
    36 |         setContent("");
    37 |         setUserId("");
```

Here is the full contents of my typed version of AddPostForm.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { unwrapResult } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { RootState } from "../../app/store";
import { addNewPost } from "./postsSlice";

export default function AddPostForm() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const [addRequestStatus, setAddRequestStatus] = useState("idle");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const users = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.users);

  const onTitleChanged = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };
  const onContentChanged = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    setContent(e.target.value);
  };
  const onAuthorChanged = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setUserId(e.target.value);
  };

  const canSave = [title, content, userId].every(Boolean) && addRequestStatus === "idle";

  const onSavePostClicked = async () => {
    if (canSave) {
      try {
        setAddRequestStatus("pending");
        const result = await dispatch(addNewPost({ title, content, user: userId }));
        unwrapResult(result);
        setTitle("");
        setContent("");
        setUserId("");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed to save the post: ", err);
      } finally {
        setAddRequestStatus("idle");
      }
    }
  };

  const usersOptions = users.map(user => (
    <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>
      {user.name}
    </option>
  ));

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Add a new post</h2>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="postTitle">Post Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="postTitle" name="postTitle" value={title} onChange={onTitleChanged} />
        <label htmlFor="postAuthor">Author:</label>
        <select id="postAuthor" value={userId} onChange={onAuthorChanged}>
          <option value=""></option>
          {usersOptions}
        </select>
        <label htmlFor="postContent">Content:</label>
        <textarea id="postContent" name="postContent" value={content} onChange={onContentChanged} />
        <button type="button" onClick={onSavePostClicked} disabled={!canSave}>Save post</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```

And here is the full contents of my typed version of redux-essentials-example-app/src/features/posts/postsSlice.tsx:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { RootState } from "../../app/store";
import { client } from "../../api/client";

export interface PostState {
  posts: Post[],
  status: "idle" | "loading" | "succeeded" | "failed",
  error: string | null,
}

export interface Post {
  id: string,
  date: string,
  title: string,
  content: string,
  user: string,
  reactions: Reactions,
}

export interface Reactions {
  thumbsUp: number,
  hooray: number,
  heart: number,
  rocket: number,
  eyes: number,
  [key: string]: number,
}

const initialState: PostState = {
  posts: [],
  status: "idle",
  error: null,
};

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/fetchPosts", async () => {
  const response = await client.get("/fakeApi/posts");
  return response.posts;
});

interface InitialPost {
  title: string,
  content: string,
  user: string,
}

export const addNewPost = createAsyncThunk<Post, InitialPost>(
  "posts/addNewPost",
  async (initialPost) => {
    const response = await client.post("/fakeApi/posts", { post: initialPost });
    return response.post;
  }
);

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    postUpdated: (state, action) => {
      const { id, title, content } = action.payload;
      const existingPost = state.posts.find(post => post.id === id);

      if (existingPost) {
        existingPost.title = title;
        existingPost.content = content;
      }
    },
    reactionAdded: (state, action) => {
      const { postId, reaction } = action.payload;
      const existingPost = state.posts.find((post: Post) => post.id === postId);
      if (existingPost) {
        existingPost.reactions[reaction]++;
      }
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchPosts.pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "succeeded";
      state.posts = state.posts.concat(action.payload);
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchPosts.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
      if (action.error.message) {
        state.error = action.error.message;
      }
    });
    builder.addCase(addNewPost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.posts.push(action.payload);
    });
  },
});

export const { postUpdated, reactionAdded } = postsSlice.actions;

export function selectAllPosts(state: RootState) {
  return state.posts.posts;
}

export function selectPostById(state: RootState, postId: string) {
  return state.posts.posts.find((post: Post) => post.id === postId);
}

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

I looked at the source code of Redux Toolkit and the `ActionTypesWithOptionalErrorAction` type is not exported, so it seems that the object being passed to `unwrapResult` needs to be a certain shape rather than declared as a certain type. The type error says the `payload` property is missing, but it's definitely there if I comment out the `unwrapResult` call and instead inspect the object with `console.log(result)`. So it seems to be an issue of getting the types correct rather than a logical error in the code. How do I type this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this while trying to solve the same problem. Rather than create a `useAppDispatch()` function to fiddle with the types, I realised that my store from configureMiddleware wasn’t including the thunk types as dispatch actions.

On [this page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#middleware-callback-notation-for-configurestore), they say that using a callback to the middleware definition will include the correct typing. Where I had been using:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: […getDefaultMiddleware(), logger]
})
```

changing that to

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger)
})
```

actually fixed the problem because `store.dispatch()` now included the `AsyncThunkAction` in the list of accepted parameter types. This is a better solution but I wish it was included in the redux toolkit docs about `configureStore`.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. It's necessary to specify the "dispatch" type when calling `useDispatch` from react-redux. This is described in [Usage With TypeScript: Getting the `Dispatch` Type](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type).

In the end, I added these extra types to the file where my Redux store is being created:

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export function useAppDispatch() {
  return useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
}
```

And then in src/features/posts/AddPostForm.tsx, I imported `useAppDispatch` instead of `useDispatch` and used that.